# Corona app reloads after inserting data in SQL Database

Tags: sql, lua, coronasdk

Every time I insert new data into my SQL Database my app will reload, going back to the start screen and printing the default startup things to my console.

Comment: Be specific in what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Theres not really much more to say. I use the following code to attempt to add data to my database, and when it restarts my app.   sql = "INSERT INTO FluidData (Date,Time,Fluid) \nVALUES (".."\'"..currentDate.."\'"..",".."\'"..currentTime.."\'"..",".."\'"..fluidInputData.."\'"..");"
            db:exec(sql)          @KumarKS